# Referring capture group in re.match() in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Hi this is the string I want to match

`mystr = "mykey/20161010/20161010"`

so far my `regex` is like this

`re.match("mykey/([2-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9])/[.]*", mystr)`

As you can see, I am using One `Capture group`. I want to replace the `[.]*` by referring the Capture group I have already created. How should I do this?

PS : I am using `Python 2.7`

**Update 1**
Based on the answers so far, I have tried this(I have simplified the example little bit), but does not seem to be working...

```
>>> mystr = "mykey/20/20"

>>> print re.match("mykey\/([2-9][0-9])\/[.]*", mystr)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7faf96ddf558>

>>> print re.match("mykey\/([2-9][0-9])\/.*", mystr)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7faf96ddf558>

>>> print re.match("mykey\/([2-9][0-9])\/\1", mystr)
None
```

I am getting `None` when trying to refer the `Capture group`. Am I missing something?

**Update 2: Finally Working...**
Hope this helps someone looking for the answer. Adding additional `backslash(ie \)` did the trick

```
>>> import re
>>> mystr = "mykey/20160610/20160610"
>>> re.match("mykey/([2-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9])/\\1", mystr)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fe352145558>
```

Comment: `[.]` matches a literal DOT, it is not present in your input.

Comment: You're looking for backreferences. They go like `\1`, `\2`, …, with the number being the index of the capturing parenthesizes in your regexp.

Comment: As a sidenote, I would simply match `[0-9]{8}` and test for a valid date after. It would avoid invalid days such as 20150229, while providing a consistent handling for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mykey\/([2-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9])\/\1
```

Use `\1` - to capture the exact match produced by the first capturing group which is `[2-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9]` in this case.

Shorter version of the same would be

```
mykey\/([2-9]\d{3}[0-1]\d[0-3]\d)\/\1
```

Comment: Also you can shorten `[0-1]` to `[01]`

Comment: Beware of `\d` though, it is only equivalent to `[0-9]` on byte patterns, not on strings. If you use `\d`, you must be certain the code after will not choke on other digits, such as `٤٢`. Granted, he's using python2 at the moment, but that will bite when he moves to python3.

Comment: @vkp, this does not seem to be working. I have updated my question. Am I missing something here

Comment: use `print re.match(r'mykey\/([2-9][0-9])\/\1', mystr)`